# Primefaces -DataTable - Internal Sort

Tags: primefaces

can we do a internal sorting in primeface datetable ? If i have column a ,b ,c. can i sort the column c and then internally by column b in p:dataTable.

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">
        <p:column headerText="Model">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="a">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="b">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="c">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSortingMultiple.jsf

**P.S** Don't forget pressing CTRL or Cmd :)

Comment: is there a way to sort withour pressing CTRL ?